# find files in subdirectories only with python

Tags: python

I have a parent folder (`PF`) with child folders (`CF1`, `CF2`, `CF3`...) and files both in the parent folder (`PFf1.csv`, `PFf2.csv`,...) and children folders (`CF1f1.csv`, `CF1f2.csv`, `CF2f1.csv`, `CF2f2.csv`,...)

I want to find only the files in the children folders (`CF1f1.csv`, `CF1f2.csv`, `CF2f1.csv`, `CF2f2.csv`,...) and ignore the files in the parent folder.

All the examples I have seen in stackoverflow and the internet are of the form:

```
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(rootDir):
   for f in files:
      print(f)
```

which finds the files in the parent folder also.  I have tried a to modify this to:

- loop through the subfolders
- on the walk, test when the new parent folder is in the original list of subfolders, then branch into an if statement

but without success.  I feel this should be easy, but I am new to python and cannot figure it out.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your loop gives you the path to the current folder, you can check if it is different than the `rootDir` (provided `rootDir` is a full path ofcourse):

```
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    if folder != rootDir:
        for f in files:
            print(f)
```

Answer (score 3):

Walk is too much if all you want is the files in the directories in a given directory. For that I would write:

```
for name in os.listdir(base):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(base, name)):
       for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(base, name)):
           if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(base, name, file)):
               print(os.path.join(base, name, file))
```

Sure, there is some redundant `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get all of the sub directories in the root directory using [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and putting a check with [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir):

```
>>> from os import listdir
>>> from os.path import isfile, isdir, join

>>> root_dir = './PF'
>>> sub_dirs = [join(root_dir, dir) for dir in listdir(root_dir) if isdir(join(root_dir, dir))]
>>> sub_dirs
['./PF/CF2', './PF/CF1']
```

And then iterate over all the sub-directories again using `os.listdir` to get files in them. You can use [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to check for only files:

```
>>> sub_dir_files = [f for subdir in sub_dirs for f in listdir(subdir) if isfile(join(subdir, f))]
>>> sub_dir_files
['CF2f2.txt', 'CF2f1.txt', 'CF1f2.txt', 'CF1f1.txt']
```